# Fix dependencies without updating package?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, chrome

I updated my Debian installation at home and it updated `chromium` to the (IMO) awfull 35.0 version. I removed it by using `apt-get remove chromium` and `apt-get autoremove`. I went [here](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/chromium-browser/34.0.1847.137-1/#chromium_34.0.1847.137-1) and grabbed the .deb for the 34.0 version I had previously installed. I used `dpkg -i filename.deb` to install it, but there were unmet dependencies:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of chromium:
 chromium depends on libc6 (>= 2.15); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.13-38+deb7u3.
 chromium depends on libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11); however:
  Version of libfontconfig1:amd64 on system is 2.9.0-7.1.
 chromium depends on libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.1); however:
  Package libgcrypt20 is not installed.
 chromium depends on libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0:amd64 on system is 2.33.12+really2.32.4-5.
 chromium depends on libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0); however:
  Package libpango-1.0-0 is not installed.
 chromium depends on libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0); however:
  Package libpangocairo-1.0-0 is not installed.
 chromium depends on libudev1 (>= 183); however:
  Package libudev1 is not installed.
 chromium depends on chromium-inspector; however:
  Package chromium-inspector is not installed.
```

Which I thought was odd, since it claims some libraries are "too old", even though I just updated the system (and `chromium`, which I assume depends on those libraries being in their latest version too).

Anyway I used `apt-get -f install` to fix them, but apt "fixed" it by updating the package to the latest version (35.0) and downloading the dependencies in their latest version too.

So... Is there a way to automatically fix those dependencies without updating chromium to 35.0, or do I have to download every dependency in their "correct" version? Wouldn't that cause some conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I only needed to install `chromium-inspector` (not to be confused with `chromium-browser-inspector`) and `chromium`. For some reason it "fixed" the other dependencies.

The procedure was the following:

- Export bookmarks to a .html file (via Chromium's Bookmark Manager)
- Backup configs (`cp -r ~/.config/chromium BAK`)
- `apt-get purge chromium`
- `apt-get autoremove` (to remove `chromium-inspector`)
- `rm -rf ~/.config/chromium` (because the profile was updated to 35.0 and conflicts with 34.0)
- Download [chromium_34.0](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140517T222731Z/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium_34.0.1847.137-1_amd64.deb) and [chromium-inspector_34.0](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20140517T222731Z/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium-inspector_34.0.1847.137-1_all.deb) (links for amd64).
- `cd` into the download folder and `dpkg -i $(ls | grep -i inspector)` and then `dpkg -i $(ls | grep -i amd)` (for amd64)
- Finally, `apt-mark hold chromium` and `apt-mark hold chromium-inspector`
- Import the exported bookmarks and re-download extensions, etc.

Comment: worked for me with Chromium 57 http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20170902T040904Z/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium_57.0.2987.98-1%7Edeb8u1_amd64.deb when I got  chromium : Conflicts: libnettle4

Answer (score 1):

You want to hold that package at it's current version. Make sure you have `apt-mark` installed. After installing chromium version 34, use this command

```
apt-mark hold chromium
```

Then rerun

```
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm now getting [an error](http://pastebin.com/kvexVvZL) when trying to fix the dependencies.

Comment: It looks like you have several packages that are `not installable` for some reason, libgcrypt20 (>= 1.6.1), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libudev1 (>= 183). They may no longer be available for download. I would use `aptitude` to see if it can resolve the dependencies. It's never easy to go backwards in packages. :(